# ESP32 using Async web server & Now protocol at same time?

Tags: arduino, webserver, esp32

I'm looking for a way to run in a single ESP32 board an Async web server to give a "User web local interface". In this interface I would like to write a text in a textfield which activate an action on my ESP32 board.

Until this point I do all and it work fine !

But the action I want to do is to send to an other ESP32 an information via ESP NOW protocol.

For information I've already use both part of code (Async part and NOW part) separately and it work fine but mixed together I can reach my local web server, I can write my command on my textfield this is going to run the good action in the first ESP32 and this action send with NOW. But looking my SerialMonitor the delivery fail ...

Here is my main board code :

```
    //*******************************Include***************************************// 
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "SPIFFS.h"
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

//*******************************Oled Screen***************************************//
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels

#define OLED_RESET  -1//4 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

//*******************************VARIABLES***************************************//
//Define Button pin
const int UpBtn = 2; // 
const int ValBtn = 4; //
const int DownBtn = 5; //
int curseur = 0; 

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Auxiliar variables to store the current output state
String output26State = "off";
String output27State = "off";

// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
const int output26 = 26;
const int output27 = 27;

// Structur for ESP NOW
typedef struct struct_message {
  char a[32];
  int b;
  float c;
  String d;
  bool e;
} struct_message;
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x24, 0x6F, 0x28, 0x38, 0xD1, 0xA4};
// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

//*******************************Set web server***************************************//

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "########";
const char* password = "########";

//WiFiServer server(80);
AsyncWebServer server(80);

//Not Found Page 
void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

//*******************************ESP NOW***************************************//

void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
  Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}

//*******************************SETUP***************************************//

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("####--WIFI PART--#####");
  // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(output26, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output27, OUTPUT);
  // Set outputs to LOW
  digitalWrite(output26, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output27, LOW);

  // Init ESP-NOW
  Serial.println("####--ESP NOW PART--#####");

   // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for Send CB to
  // get the status of Trasnmitted packet
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);

  // Register peer
  esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
  peerInfo.channel = 0;  
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;

  // Add peer        
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("*** ESP_RDY ***");

  //ASYNC SERVER
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if(!SPIFFS.begin()){
       Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
       return;
  }

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.on("/home", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", "text/html");
  });

  server.on("/qwb7.min.js", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/qwb7.min.js", "text/javascript");
  });
  server.on("/jquery-ui.min.css", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/jquery-ui.min.css", "text/css");
  });

  server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String inputMessage;
    String inputParam;
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_1;
      //showMyMessage(input
      if (inputMessage == "ON"){
        AllumerLed();
      }else if (inputMessage == "OFF"){
        EteindreLed();
      }
      // OLED


    }
    // GET input2 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input2=<inputMessage>
    /*else if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_2;
    }
    // GET input3 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input3=<inputMessage>
    else if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_3;
    }*/
    else {
      inputMessage = "No message sent";
      inputParam = "none";
    }
    Serial.println(inputMessage);
    /*request->send(200, "text/html", "HTTP GET request sent to your ESP on input field (" 
                                     + inputParam + ") with value: " + inputMessage +
                                     "<br><a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");*/
  });

  server.onNotFound(notFound);
  server.begin();

  //Gestion OLED
  Serial.println("####--OLED PART--#####");
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { // Address 0x3C for 128x32
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }
  Serial.println("*** OLED_RDY ***");
  display.clearDisplay();

  //Gestion Push buttons
  Serial.println("####--BTN PART--#####");
  pinMode(UpBtn, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(ValBtn, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(DownBtn, INPUT_PULLUP);

  Serial.print("*** FULL_RDY_MSG ***"); //Afficher que la carte est prète à l'emploi

}

//*******************************LOOP***************************************//

void loop(){ 

}

//*******************************ACTIONS***************************************//

void AllumerLed()
{
  //uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x24, 0x6F, 0x28, 0x38, 0xD1, 0xA4};
  strcpy(myData.a, "LED ON");
    myData.b = random(1,20);
    myData.c = 1.2;
    myData.d = "1";
    myData.e = false;

    // Send message via ESP-NOW
    esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *) &myData, sizeof(myData));

    if (result == ESP_OK) {
      Serial.println("Sent with success");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Error sending the data");
    }
}
void EteindreLed()
{
  uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x24, 0x6F, 0x28, 0x38, 0xD1, 0xA4};
  strcpy(myData.a, "LED OFF");
    myData.b = random(1,20);
    myData.c = 1.2;
    myData.d = "0";
    myData.e = false;

    // Send message via ESP-NOW
    esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *) &myData, sizeof(myData));

    if (result == ESP_OK) {
      Serial.println("Sent with success");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Error sending the data");
    }
}
//******************************END****************************************//
```

And here is my slave ESP NOW code :

```
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>


// Define Oled Screen 
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 32 // OLED display height, in pixels

#define OLED_RESET  -1//4 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

// Structure example to receive data
// Must match the sender structure
typedef struct struct_message {
    char a[32];
    int b;
    float c;
    String d;
    bool e;
} struct_message;

const int ledPin = 27;

// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

// callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
  Serial.print("Bytes received: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("Char: ");
  Serial.println(myData.a);
  Serial.print("Int: ");
  Serial.println(myData.b);
  Serial.print("Float: ");
  Serial.println(myData.c);
  Serial.print("String: ");
  Serial.println(myData.d);
  Serial.print("Bool: ");
  Serial.println(myData.e);
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.println("Led OK");
  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }else{
    Serial.println("initializing ESP-NOW DONE");
  }

  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);

    //Gestion OLED

  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) { // Address 0x3C for 128x32
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }
}

void loop() {

  if (myData.d == "0"){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }else if (myData.d == "1"){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprise your ESP-NOW slave code works as you claimed. For ESP-NOW slave, it needs to be in `WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP)`, see [official examples](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/ESPNow).

Comment: I've been follow the `randomnerdtutorials` all part work separately but not interesting me ... I think I'll use 2 ESP32 board as main card One for the Async and the seconde one for the Now communication and both card will be linked together via I2C ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that a 2.4ghz WIFI has 13 channels that run on different frequencies. So you either have to change your router's channel to 1 channel (default espnow channel) or you have to tell the espnow transmitter to send the signal to your wifi channel.

simple code:

```
int getWiFiChannel(const char *ssid) {
  if (int32_t n = WiFi.scanNetworks()) {
      for (uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
          if (!strcmp(ssid, WiFi.SSID(i).c_str())) {
              return WiFi.channel(i);
          }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}

  int channel=getWiFiChannel(YOUR_WIFI_NAME);

  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(true);
  esp_wifi_set_channel(channel, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE);
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(false);
```